# Update Query Using Stored Procedure and Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure with a parameter that will update my field in a table of mine called `ImportTemplate`. I want it to let me enter any value in there when I run the stored procedure so it will update the `FileReference` column in the `ImportTemplate` table.

The following is what I have written but it does not seem to work!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateFileReference] (@FileReference nvarchar)
AS 
BEGIN
   UPDATE [dbo].[ImportTemplate]
   SET FileReference = null
   WHERE FileReference >= @FileReference
END
```

First time using this can anyone help!

Comment: What does not work? do you get errors?

Comment: First thing I see is `Nvarchar` does not have size declared. Read @Aaron-Bertrand's blog [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). What that means that if do you specify size, it is defaulted to `nvarchar(1)`. Additionally `>=` is not good operator on string types unless `FileReference` is numeric type and  you are doing implicit conversion.

Comment: I want it to update FileReference to any Value I choose not just null

Comment: than you need to `SET FileReference = @FileReference` but you still need `WHERE` clause otherwise all rows will become new value.

Comment: @Ap9_Jacka and where you are going to get that value ??Read `Vladimir` comments you need to define either new variable for setting FileReference value or if you need to set it's value to ' @FileReference' then  use SET FileReference = @FileReference. Also define nVarchar size.